# Category shorthand not allowed in this regular expression dialect in TypeScript

Tags: regex, typescript

I tried to use a regular expression in TypeScript:

```
const pass = /^[\pL\pM\pN_-]+$/u.test(control.value) || !control.value;
```

but I got this error:

> Category shorthand not allowed in this regular expression dialect in Typescript

Why am I getting this error, and how can I fix it?

Comment: This question is being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412601).

Comment: Well, do you know what a category shorthand is? Do you understand where your regular expressions use them? Do you know which ones, if any, are allowed? If not, did you try to check the documentation?

Comment: Not sure why my comment was flagged and deleted. I will repeat: do you get that exact error message ?

Comment: @Vega: I can confirm that the IDE I'm using (Webstorm) shows that _exact_ error message.

Comment: @Cerbus, I tested in VSCode, and it passed, no error. Must be my settings? In WebStorm, I indeed got the message

Comment: This is a warning message, not an error message. Depending on your editor setting you might not get it. This doesn't interfere on the code run

Comment: @Vega Plain old JavaScript doesn't allow that, so you probably have the IDE configured to transpile that regex.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That regex shorthand (`\pL`) isn't allowed.

You'll need to use the full versions (`\p{L}`), instead of the shorthand:

```
const pass = /^[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}_-]+$/u.test(control.value) || !control.value;
```

Comment: Here's a [playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAbgQwDYFcCmMC8MBEAJASxwG4YAoUSWABwQgixgHoA9AbQB1qBvAGQF8u3ALKCeAOX4B9ALQBdANQASJigB0UNNAAUiVGgCUMAD7GYAQj3piFcBBBI0apCADm27rXr8DZIA)

Comment: Is the short version not allowed in JS, or TS? Do you have any links explaining this?

Comment: My IDE is giving me a similar error for JS files, @JuanMendes. I don't have any other info on this other than _"apparently the language doesn't support that"_

Comment: @JuanMendes: The regexes are equivalent, it's just that the shorthand isn't supported.

Comment: @JuanMendes The short version is not supported in JavaScript, see [Unicode property escapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes). I don't know the details of what's supported in TypeScript, but it appears that it's just relying on the underlying Unicode property escapes support in JavaScript with a somewhat more descriptive error message. The error message in JavaScript on FF is "Uncaught SyntaxError: invalid class property name in regular expression".